Lambda function Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value error
My lambda function produces the above error when I send a JSON string in the message body of the SQS queue that acts as a trigger for my function. But when I send the same string directly to the function as part of the test code on the AWS console it works. I am sending the message from the AWS console.
my string:
 "{\"cc\":[\"ppp@example.com\"],\"templateId\":\"xxx\",\"mailAttributes\":{\"key1\":\"abc\",\"key2\":\"xyz\"}}"

My lambda function:
public void handleRequest(String payload, Context context) throws JsonProcessingException {

        try{
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            MessagePayload messagePayload = objectMapper.readValue(payload, MessagePayload.class) ;
            context.getLogger().log("Input: " + messagePayload);


        }
catch ( JsonProcessingException e){
            context.getLogger().log("Error in parsing json"+ e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}

When I pass the string directly to the function in the test area of the console:

but when I pass the string as message body in the queue on the console and it acts as trigger to my function it produces the error.

error:

